# F# extending constrained array

Tags: generics, f#, extension-methods, generic-programming

Say I have the following snippet

```ml
type 'T``[]`` when 'T : (static member (+) : 'T -> 'T -> 'T) with
    member inline self.sum = Array.fold ( + ) self
```

It's hopefully obvious that I want to add an extension method only when 'T supports the `+` operator.

However, I keep getting the following errors:

`Error  FS0957  One or more of the declared type parameters for this type extension have a missing or wrong type constraint not matching the original type constraints on '[]<_>'`

Is this specific of an extension method possible? If it is, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with was

```
type 'T``[]`` with
    member inline this.mysum< ^T when ^T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^T -> ^T)>() = 
        Array.reduce (fun v1 v2 -> (^T : (static member (+): ^T * ^T -> ^T)  (v1, v2)))
```

which still doesn't work (at least in FSI - haven't tried compiling). I'm not sure this is possible at all.

Instead, I suggest you use the `IEnumerable<_>` extension methods in `System.Linq`:

```
open System.Linq
[| 1..10 |].Sum()
```